# Xcode Caching Files

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a storyboard which contains views which simply refuse to change. If I make changes to the controls they're not reflected in either the simulator or a phone. I don't have a 'Derived Data' folder under /Library/Developer so I can't delete it. I have, however done a clean, with no effect. There must be another cache somewhere it's using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fair amount of scouring, I eventually cleared the cache by emptying `/Users/Library/My user/Developer/Derived` data, then doing a clean, then restarting Xcode.